# How to push to a new viewController from UITableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

could someone help tell me where I'm going wrong? I'm trying to push to a new view controller from a table view but it's not doing anything, it prints in the console so its registering but it's not pushing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nU5Dn.png)

```
extension HostedVC: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return hostItems.count
    }
           
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "hostedCell", for: indexPath) as! HostedTableViewCell
        let post = hostItems[indexPath.row]
        cell.eventNameLable.text = post.eventName
        cell.eventNameLable.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.42, green: 0.33, blue: 0.56, alpha: 1.00)
        cell.dateLable.text = post.startDate
        cell.dateLable.textColor = UIColor.init(red: 61/255, green: 75/255, blue: 99/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        cell.logo.image = UIImage(named: "networkingIMG")
        let backgroundView = UIView()
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.73, green: 0.73, blue: 0.73, alpha: 1.00)
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundView
        cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 80
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let iP = hostItems[indexPath.row]
        print(iP.eventName)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(iP.id, forKey: "SelectedId")
        let vc = HistoryCellPageVC(event: iP)
        hostedVC?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == .delete) {
            // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)
            hostItems.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        }
    }
    
    func openEvent(_ hostItems: Hosted) {
        let vc = HistoryCellPageVC(event: hostItems)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to add `UITableViewDelegate`, that's why didSelectRowAt doesn't run.

Simply change
`extension HostedVC: UITableViewDataSource`

to

`extension HostedVC: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate`

By the way, you dont need to call `tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)`.